# 7 years old and later

Tags: meaning, differences

I am pretty confused with this statement

"documents which are 7 years old and later should only be migrated"

does it means "2007 to 2014" ,or "2007 to old"

Comment: What would make it clearer is quoting what should happen to the other documents (the use of *only* suggests that destruction might be mentioned somewhere).

Comment: Thanks for the comments,yes i already got it clear from author, just wanted to know what it actually means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am pretty confused with this statement

you should be.

If you want to say 2007-now you could write, amongst other variations, "7 years old or newer"

If you want to say 'beginning of time'-2007 you could write, amongst other variations, "7 years old or older"

old/young/new specify an age. later/earlier specify a time. These don't go so well together.

"documents which are 7 years old and later should only be migrated"

"later" possibly refers to "written later" , which would mean "newer". Additionally "should only be migrated" indicates that the documents that are "earlier" require some more processing, which backs up the proposition that later means "newer", however, this is wholly contextual.

Since this seems work-related, for the best answer, if possible, ask whoever is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this as documents newer than 7 years old, or as you say 2007 to 2014.

- A document written in 2006 would be written earlier than 2007.
- A document written in 2008 would be written later than 2007.

Answer (score 0):

It means, documents that are 7 yearls old, 6 years old, 5 years old, etc., till now. If you want to mean 7 years old and older, you should write :

"documents that are old by at least 7 years should be migrated.

also "which" is not the right word there. it should be "that"

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this question is being asked demonstrates the potential for misunderstanding when arithmetic is combined with English.  There are several other examples of this, such as "up to half price sale".  In my opinion it is always best to be a clear as possible.

Hence, these could be used for clarity

- "documents that are at least 7 years old" would mean from the dawn of time up to 2007
- "documents that are no more than 7 years old" would mean 2007 to 2014

I believe that the original sentence queried means "no more than 7 years old", but it may be worth checking with the author.